# C# calculations differ between const and variable locals?

Tags: c#, mono, constants, double

I was setting up a pop quiz for my colleagues about the Banker's Rounding approach that C# uses in the `Math.Round` function. But while preparing the question in repl.it I got a result that I thought was pretty weird. At first I was working with an array, but I've managed to boil it down to this snippet to find a small reproduction scenario:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    double x = 10.5;
    System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                             arg0: x,
                             arg1: System.Math.Round(x));


    const double y = 10.5;
    System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                             arg0: y,
                             arg1: System.Math.Round(y));
  }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Math.Round(10.5) = 10
Math.Round(10.5) = 11
```

(I've also tried it with `decimal` numbers, which didn't result in any difference between the calculation methods: both resulted in 10 which is correct according to the Banker's Rounding rule.)

Now, I'm guessing this might have something to do with the `const double` version getting precompiled, but I'd expect - and I'm not sure this is reasonable - the precompiled version to use the same rules for rounding and/or (I'm not sure what the exact cause is) suffer from the exact same roundoff error - effectively, I'd *expect* it to perform the exact same calculation, just at a different time.

It is somewhat hard to find more information on this behavior, partially because I'm not sure whether I've ran into a bug in `Math.Round` (which is, apparently, has some issues as well) or something that is related to the precompilation that `const`s allow, but I'm guessing it's the latter - and searching for things like "c# const different result" gave me nothing immediately useful.

So my question is, **can anyone explain this output** in terms of "this only happens if the compiler runs on platform X and the program then runs on platform Y because Z"?

(Edit: sorry, forgot to post the repl.it link. [Here](https://repl.it/repls/IdleSingleFiletype#main.cs) it is!)

Comment: Please share the framework version which you are using. I'm getting 10 for both!

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay He said he ran it in repl.it, it's reproducible there.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/SeriousCurlyNet#main.cs

Comment: repl.it is running under mono 6.10.0.104 as of this writing

Comment: Bug in Mono 6.10.0.104 perhaps?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sMilN8) in fiddle.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Looks like it. Tested here: https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online/ with Mono 5.10.1 and both are 10. Mono 6.0 produces 10 & 11.

Comment: Odd bug really. `10.5` is exactly representable with no rounding issues in IEEE 754, so we can't really blame it on that.

Comment: Really rare but evidence says that is a Mono version specific behavior when Math.Round operates over constants and double literals based on the repl.it code you plublished i test two more cases: a) declare a double variable and test the constant value to it (results 10) and passing literal 10.5 as argument (results 11). Even more, I introduced a method with a double parameter who invokes the Print of the value and the Math.Round() result. In every invocation the result is 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a bug with the mono compiler, but I encountered a similar problem [here](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/36/3661/bug.html), and the code change that was made by the contributor [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/243/files).

My guess is that the Round function is changing the decimal places in the tests to the value **X**, but with the constant **Y** the original value does not change.

Below is a possible workaround:

```
double x = 10.5;
const double y = 10.5;

System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                         arg0: x,
                         arg1: System.Math.Round(x, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 11
System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                         arg0: y,
                         arg1: System.Math.Round(y, 0 , MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); 
// 11
System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                         arg0: x,
                         arg1: System.Math.Round(y, 0 , MidpointRounding.ToEven));
// 10
System.Console.WriteLine(format: "Math.Round({0}) = {1}",
                         arg0: y,
                         arg1: System.Math.Round(y, 0 , MidpointRounding.ToEven));
// 10
```

I was able to do Math.Round correctly in .NET, .NET Core 3.0 in both x_86 and x_64 on windows 10.

Perhaps it is something to report on the mono github as a issue. If you do, you can get the system and compiler information with the below commands in the command line window at Repl.it

> System info: uname -a

*Linux 52d579a3a5fc 5.4.0-1019-gcp #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 15:46:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

> Complier version: mono --version

*Mono JIT compiler version 6.10.0.104 (tarball Fri Jun 26 19:38:24 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. [www.mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com)
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug
Interpreter:   yes
LLVM:          yes(610)
Suspend:       hybrid
GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)*

Interesting question! please let me know if it helped you.